# How can I make PHP think that the files are in a parent directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

As the title says, how can I make PHP think that the files are in a parent directory?

For example, my file structure looks like this:

```
- website
- - css
- - js
- - images
```

And I want PHP to think that the directory `js` is always in `../js` (parent directory)? Can this be done with `.htaccess`?

Thanks.

Comment: visit here:http://paulmayne.org/blog/2008/12/use-htaccess-to-rewrite-folder-structure/

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule in `/website/js/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/js/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /js/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current directory to something like this:

```
<?php
    // Get current directory
    $cur_dir = getcwd();

    //change the dir
    chdir("../js");

    //do something here

    //back to your main current dir if you have still something to do
    chdir($cur_dir);
?>
```